# Oracle ODP.Net With Entity Framework 6 - TypeInitializationException - CreateConnection()

Tags: entity-framework-6, odp.net

I have created to apps, first with ODP.Net and without Entity - works great.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

        //using connection string attributes to connect to Oracle Database
        con.ConnectionString = "user id=****;password=****;data source=" +
            "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server.org.net)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=ora1)))";
        con.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);

        OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT ITEM FROM TEST.ORDERS";

        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",
                reader[0]);
        }
        reader.Close();

        // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Second program is using ODP.Net and EntityFramework and manaly created Entity Data Model class (which was tested on Npgsql.EntityFramework and works great, perfect copy of the database from Oracle).
The application returns the error:

```
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory.CreateConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(System.String)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(System.String, System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(System.Data.Entity.DbContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
```

I don't know what is wrong.
This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql"/>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=testDb;User Id=***;Password=***;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=***;Password=***;Data Source=SampleDataSource2"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource2" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server.org.net)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=ora1)))"/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
    <settings>
      <setting name="TraceLevel" value="7" />
      <setting name="TraceFileLocation" value="C:\"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How did you install ODP.NET? If you got it from NuGet make sure to get the one with "Official" in the title. A proper installation of ODP.NET will add entries to machine.config (or your app.config) to make it able to be used as a ClassFactory.

Comment: Yes, I used NuGet and "Official" version - similarly, as I did for PostgreSQL (which worked). In app.confg I added only SampleDataSource2, rest is autogenerated. Look at connectionString - 'Data Source=SampleDataSource2' is this OK?

Comment: Is there by any chance an internal or nested exception being thrown  that contains an ORA- error? (For example ORA-12145) When the exception pops up look at the details and see if you can drill down and see an ORA error. That may be all this is.

Comment: I found one bug and now I have something like this: ORA-00955 when doing this:
`dbContext.Orders.Select(m => m.PlanNo).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m);`

Comment: Sounds like you have moved way past the connection error and are onto something entirely different.

Comment: It was a simple error resulting from lack of access to debug information.
New problem are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819307/oracle-odp-net-with-entity-framework-6-ora-00955-on-select-from-table-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in app.config section:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I had to remove:

```
<settings>
```

Nevertheless, the application still does not work, but for a different reason.

Comment: Ah! It was trying to write a trace to C:\ which is not allowed for non admin processes!