# Oracle ODP.Net With Entity Framework 6 - ORA-00955 on Select from Table View

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have created two apps, first with ODP.Net and without Entity - works great.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

    //using connection string attributes to connect to Oracle Database
    con.ConnectionString = "user id=****;password=****;data source=" +
        "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server.org.net)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=ora1)))";
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);

    OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ITEM FROM TEST.ORDERS";

    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",
            reader[0]);
    }
    reader.Close();

    // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

TEST.ORDERS is a View.

Second program is using ODP.Net and EntityFramework and manaly created DbSet class (which was tested on Npgsql.EntityFramework and works great, perfect copy of the view from Oracle). The application returns error: ORA-00955.
I noticed that when the change name of the "Schema" to one that does not have a view 'ORDER', the program creates my table with the same name.
This is my begining of DbSet:

```
[Table("ORDERS", Schema = "TEST")]
```

It is possible that it is wrong. But I do not know how to build the entities that will have access to this view. The user has permission only to SELECT. I want do read-only operations.

Comment: ORA-00955 is the _name is already used by an existing object_ error. Are you sure that is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It seems to me that for some reason my application wants to create such a table, but can not because there is a view. I just want to read the data from this view.

Comment: Ok we need to see the code that is receiving the application error.

Comment: Here You go: http://pastebin.com/n4WrZgv7

Comment: Did you figure this out?  This is the exact issue I seem to be facing.

Comment: I am also facing this issue... will any one figure this out ?..

Comment: Same problem, just trying to select from a view and it's trying to create something.  Simplest out of the box case, nuget EF6 and Oracle EF packages, map the view, .To_List() the contents.

Comment: I have had problems before with stuff named `ORDER` in SQL statements; the solution being to use `[ORDER]` instead, in the case of table or view names. Can't remember if it was SQL Server or Oracle though...

Comment: @Bamdad The only problem here is that migrations aren't disabled in the EF project because the database initializer isn't set to null. It's not clear which EF version you're using and which part of the question applies too you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Keyless Entity Types` and use `ToView` fluent api in you `DbContext`. when you define an entity as `ToView` and do migrations, the `EF` assumes that view has already exist in your database and won't try to create it.

So first create model:

```
  public class KeyLessModel
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
```

And in `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<KeyLessModel>().ToView("ORDERS", "TEST");

        }

        public DbSet<KeyLessModel> KeyLessModels { get; set; }
```

For get data from view just call it like this:

```
var items = _dbContext.KeyLessModels.ToList();
```

I've tested in `EF Core 3.1` and works fine.

Comment: this is the correct way, but why the focus on the Keyless Entity? The entity could still have a key even if it relies on a view, or not?

Comment: @david-ao No view has not ``Primary Key``. View just show data from a table that has a key.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle implementation of Entity framework provider is very poor but there are some ways how to make this working.

1. Simple but annoying - using NULL or own database initializer implementation:

   ```
   Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
   ```

or

```
class DatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DatabaseContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        // your implementation
    }
}

Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
```

Set the initialized before first access to your database.

2. If you want to use migrations create your views and then add migration with ignoring changes, for instance using package console `add-migration initial -ignorechanges`. This will make EF ignoring the inconsistencies between the DB schema and model (because it checks only tables from `ALL_TABLES`, not views) so it will not try to create table. There is a bug in Oracle EF implementation that if the initial migration is empty it drops and recreates the `__MigrationHistory` table so either your initial migration must containt at least one table before you add the view migration or you need to add a table afterwards.

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<ContextClass>(null); in Global.asax